# Workflow API Roles which can approve, reject and make changes Only Listed

Tags: kentico, kentico-api

Using Kentico 11.0.26.
How do I select this option programatically when creating a workflow using [Workflow API](https://docs.kentico.com/api11/configuration/workflows#Workflows-Allowingrolestomakeworkflowsteptransitions)

[image]

EDIT: After running the code sample in link above, the very first radio button "None" gets selected. If you go to Kentico and manually select "Only listed" option, the role added programatically appears.

Comment: It might be easiest to make a workflow, read it in your code and dump out all of the properties then try changing this to see what's changed. At first glance there's no source for WorkflowInfo publicly available but as you have the code yourself you could try looking at the class with a .NET decompiler to see if you can see anything likely too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the code sample that you already linked in your post. That settings is placed directly on the step itself, so with code like this you should set it:

```
// Here Only listed security is assigned to current step.
step.StepRolesSecurity = WorkflowStepSecurityEnum.OnlyAssigned;
```

**EDIT:**

Additionally save workflow step after update StepRolesSecurity property:

```
WorkflowStepInfoProvider.SetWorkflowStepInfo(step);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code sample does not select "Only listed" radio button.  That's why I posted this question. After running it, the very first radio button "None" gets selected. If you go to Kentico and manually select "Only listed" then the role added progrmatically appears.

Comment: Now I understand your issue. It was not related to assigning specific roles, only for updating step. You should save step after you change it (after assigning roles, or after set StepRolesSecurity)  with: WorkflowStepInfoProvider.SetWorkflowStepInfo(step);

Comment: I updated my answer. Glad to hear that worked for you.